# How to compare three values from text field and if any are below/above a certain value display a message?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, int

Hi i'm trying to write a programme similar to a BMI calculator tutorial i followed and completed successfully last fortnight.

However I'm now trying to do a health programme that compares a users temperature/blood pressure and heart beat, and if any are below or above certain values to warn the user via console message.

for example 
if

- temperature <35 or >39 display a warning message or
- heart rate <60 or >150 display a warning message or
- blood pressure <100 or >150 display a warning message.

hI am unsure how to convert and compare the value as it says "Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'int'". I have the user input the value in a text field and understand that it is cannot compare text fields, so i tried to convert it to a float using `Float.parseFloat(temperatureStr);` but that didn't seem to work. Is there something that can change String `temperatureStr = temperature.getText().toString();` into an interger so I am able to compare it to a number and then display a warning message?

Comment: It probably would be better with a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if i understand you correctly you try to implement something like this:

```
class UserClassName {
int bodyTemp;
int bloodPressure;
int heartSkip;

public void getUsersValues() {
    Scanner body, temp, blood;
    body = new Scanner(System.in);
    temp = new Scanner(System.in);
    blood = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Your temp ..");
        String intputTempAsString = body.nextLine();
        try  {
            bodyTemp = Interger.parseInt(inputTempAsString);
        catch {
            throw new Exception("Your warning her");
        }

        // Do this for ever Number or Value you wanna have and it should work
}

// Methods to compare the input 
public boolean checkHeartSkiptsFrequncy() {
    return heartSkip > 60 && heartskip < 150;
}

public boolean checkBodyTemp() {
    return heartSkip > 35 && heartskip < 39;
}

public boolean checkBlood() {
    return heartSkip > 100 && heartskip < 150;
}

public boolean checkHealth() {
    if(!chechHeartSkipFrequncy) {
        System.out.println("The Frequceny of you Heartbeat ....");
    else if(!checkBodyTemp) {
        System.out.println("Your body Temp is bad...");
    else if(!checkBlood) {
        System.out.println("Your blood ....");
    else {
        System.out.println("Everything is fine")
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for. I know that is not 100% perfect but i hope this it will help you to solve your problem.

This code is also no complete solution for your problem but i tried to cover all important aspekts.

If you have any questions or improvment for me than reply to this post.

Have a nice Day and good luck man.